# Why are changes to a list made in a sub-process not showing up in the parent process?

Tags: list, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am creating a sub-process for reading a growing log file. I passed a counter ( inside of a list) into the `log_file_reader` function, and append 1 to the counter list if the line is valid. I check the counter in the main process every 5 seconds. The counter in the increases as expected in the sub-process, but it is always 0 in the main process. I checked the id of the counter; it is identical both in sub-process and main process. Why isn't the counter increasing in the main process? If i change counter to `counter = multiprocessing.Queue()` and check the `qsize()` in `log_file_reader(...)` or the main thread,  everything is working fine.

```
import subprocess
import select
import multiprocessing
import time


def log_file_reader(filename, counter):
    f = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F',filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p = select.poll()
    p.register(f.stdout)
    while True:
        if p.poll(1):
            line = f.stdout.readline().strip()
            if line:
                '''appends 1 to counter if line is valid'''
                counter.append(1)


def main():
    counter = list()  # initializes a counter in type list
    # starts up a process keep tailing file
    reader_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=log_file_reader, args=("/home/haifzhan/logfile.log", counter))
    reader_process.start()

    # main thread check the counter every 5 seconds
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print "periodically check---counter:{0},id:{1}".format(len(counter), id(counter))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # everything starts here
    main()
```

Comment: What is stopping you from using `counter = multiprocessing.Queue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain `list` objects are not shared between processes, so the `counter` in the child process is actually a completely distinct object from the `counter` in the parent. Changes you make to one will not affect the other. If you want to share the list between processes, you need to use a [`multiprocessing.Manager().list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list):

```
import subprocess
import select
import multiprocessing
import time


def log_file_reader(filename, counter):
    f = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F',filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p = select.poll()
    p.register(f.stdout)
    while True:
        if p.poll(1):
            line = f.stdout.readline().strip()
            if line:
                '''appends 1 to counter if line is valid'''
                counter.append(1)


def main():
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    counter = m.list()  # initializes a counter in type list
    # starts up a process keep tailing file
    reader_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=log_file_reader, args=("/home/haifzhan/logfile.log", counter))
    reader_process.start()

    # main thread check the counter every 5 seconds
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print "periodically check---counter:{0},id:{1}".format(len(counter), id(counter))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # everything starts here
    main()
```

If you're just using the list as a counter, though, you might as well use a [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value), rather than a list, which really is meant to be used for counting purposes, and doesn't require starting a `Manager` process:

```
import subprocess
import select
import multiprocessing
import time


def log_file_reader(filename, counter):
    f = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F',filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p = select.poll()
    p.register(f.stdout)
    while True:
        if p.poll(1):
            line = f.stdout.readline().strip()
            if line:
                '''appends 1 to counter if line is valid'''
                with counter.get_lock():
                    counter.value += 1


def main():
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0) # A process-safe int, initialized to 0
    # starts up a process keep tailing file
    reader_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=log_file_reader, args=("/home/haifzhan/logfile.log", counter))
    reader_process.start()

    # main thread check the counter every 5 seconds
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        with counter.get_lock():
            print "periodically check---counter:{0},id:{1}".format(counter.value, id(counter))
```

Comment: thanks a lot !  I figured out that list is not working for inter-processes！  I've never used `multiprocessing.Manager().list` and `multiprocessing.Value` , they are really helpful!